# How to install MemSource

Tags: installation

I am trying to install MemSource Desktop, but cannot install by double clicking on  download. Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about MemSource Editor, you will need to give the downloaded file execution permissions before double-clicking it.

Right-click on the file, select properties, go to the permission tab, select "Allow executing this file as a program".